# Angular2 trying to show a PDF

Tags: angular

I am trying to show a PDF file on my page.  For do that I am using the object tag like this and it works:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;background-color:white">
  <object data="http://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf" 
    type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="view" value="Fit" />
  </object>
</div>
```

But I need to set the object data dynamically, like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;background-color:white">
  <object data="{{url}}" 
    type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="view" value="Fit" />
  </object>
</div>
```

I've defined the url but it didn't show the PDF file.  I've created an example of waht I wanna do:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6xE1Q7YzcD8eB0K4lP8Y

Please any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Thanks and regards,
Edu

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine in Chrome.

Some browsers (IE) resolve `{{url}}" before Angular got a chance to replace the binding by the bound value which results in an error because`{{url}}` isn't a valid URL.

You can prevent that by using

```
<object [data]="url"
```

or

```
<object [attr.data]="url"
```

or

```
<object attr.data="{{url}}"
```

Comment: I am using a Mac with chrome to develop.  I've tried to use the [data], but it didn't work.
I've also tried on the plunker example I've created and it didn't work too.  Any suggestion?

Thanks and regards, Edu

Comment: What does "disn't work" mean. As mentioned I can't reproduce. Do you get an error message in the browser console? Do all three examples from my answer produce the same result?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I've tried the three ways you shown in your answer.  When I added the [data] the plunker example keeps loading and don't show the view.  Here is my test http://plnkr.co/edit/6xE1Q7YzcD8eB0K4lP8Y?p=preview Am i doing it wrong?  Thank and regards.  Edu

Comment: None of my examples look like `[data]="{{url}}"`. If you use `[]` don't use `{{}}`

Comment: You are right I was doing it wrong, but it didn't work without the {{}}.  The DOM is written but it doesn't show the pdf:
`<div style="width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;background-color:white">
      <object height="100%" type="application/pdf" width="100%" data="http://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf" internalinstanceid="41">
        <param name="view" value="Fit">
      </object>
    </div>`  [http://plnkr.co/edit/6xE1Q7YzcD8eB0K4lP8Y]